# Discrete Maths:Predicate Logic Negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Let's say we have ∀xR(x).
Is ¬(∀xR(x)) the same as ¬∀xR(x)? Does that mean that  the negation goes only to the  quantitative indicator?

Comment: The negation of "for all $x$ we have ..." is indeed "not for all $x$ we have..." (if that's what you mean to ask).

Comment: What i want to be sure about that in this example(one of many),the negation reaches only the quantitative indicator but never the quality P(or any other that is commited to the specific indicator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  The negation is the negation f the quantifificational formula ... it does not *also* (i.e. In addition to that) negate what is inside the quantifier.

So, yes, you have that:

$$\neg (\forall x \ P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \neg \forall x \ P(x)$$

In fact, this is not just an equivalence, but these two statements are really one and the same: the parentheses would merely there for your reading convenience.

Finally, it should be noted that the negation can be brought inside the quantifier, and when you do that, the negation will negate the formula on the inside, but the quantifier changes its sign:

$$\neg \forall x \ P(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x \ \neg P(x)$$

Comment: Thanks.Is there a specific name to this rule?

Comment: @Guest36 it's really not a rule ... syntactically, you can just drop the parentheses, and it is considered the *same* formula, not just an equivalent one.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Negation goes to quantifiers and changes them at the same time the truth value of statement changes w.r.t that quantifiers.

but an idea or say the meaning of a statement is still the same.

Comment: I am jealous of your handwriting :(

Comment: Thanks for that .It's neat.I was stuck in an insignificance.Yet your answer is  helpful generally for other than i seeked.